# Not able to retrieve Firebase User

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am not able to retrieve a Firebase user. Below is my Users class, just to get only required fields from Firebase User data.

```
class Users {
   final String uid;
   Users({ required this.uid });
}
```

Below is my Auth class:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:codeproject/models/users.dart';


abstract class AuthBase {
  Stream<Users> get authStateChanges;
  Future<Users> currentUser();
  Future<Users> signInAnonymously();
  Future<Users> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
  Future<Users> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
  Future<Users> signInWithGoogle();
  Future<void> signOut();
}

class AuthService implements AuthBase {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Users _userFromFirebase(User user) {
    if (user == null) {
      **return null;**
    }
    return Users(uid: user.uid);
  }
// ERROR: A value of type 'Null' can't be returned from the method '_userFromFirebase' because it has a return type of 'Users'.




  @override
  Stream<Users> get authStateChanges {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(**_userFromFirebase**);
  }
//ERROR: The argument type 'Users Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Users Function(User?)'.

  @override
  Future<Users> currentUser() async {
    final user = _auth.currentUser;
    return _userFromFirebase(**user**);
  }
//ERROR: The argument type 'User?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User'.


  @override
  Future<Users> signInAnonymously() async {
    final authResult = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
    return _userFromFirebase(**authResult.user**);
  }
//ERROR: The argument type 'User?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User'.

}
```

Error part I have highlighted with ****

Comment: Please do not add "thank you", signatures and other noise to posts: they just create more work for editors of the site. Stack Overflow is a collection of questions and answers, not a forum. Think of us as an encyclopedia. If you are worried about post attribution, a user card is already displayed on each and every one of those posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change return type to User? and Users? (I'm assuming this is your custom data type)

FirebaseAuth current user returns null if no user is logged in and User is there is a user logged in. Due to null safety, User? and User are different types.

Example:

```
Users? _userFromFirebase(User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return Users(uid: user.uid);
  }
```

Comment: still I am getting same error can not return null...

Comment: You would also have to change the Users to Users? since now it is nullable.